# Is there anyway to align these header names with their columns using css/scss?

Tags: css, sass

I am a bit stuck here with my css/scss. I want these header columns headers to align in the middle of their corresponding column. Here is the code for the col headers:

```
<li id="campaignHead">
  <label>Campaign Name</label>
  <label>Status</label>
  <label>Budget</label>
  <label>Start Date</label>
  <label>End Date</label>
</li>
```

And here is the corresponding css/scss:

```
#campaignHead{
  background-color: $thColor;
  @include li();
  justify-content: flex-start;
  label{
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

I have also created a js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hpufo/8xyo12Lg/1/

Comment: why not just use a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My main recommendation here would be to use a table as this is a clear use-case for a table.

However, if you must use a list with labels, you want to give the labels a fixed width.

Something like

```
#campaignHead label {
    width:20%;
}
```

Should fix your problem. You will also need to set your inputs to have the same width if you want things to align correctly

You could also use a grid layout to achieve something similar